# How to say "Goodbye" in Calabria

Tags: regional

In Calabria, how would one close family member bid goodbye to another family member, especially when they will not be reunited for a long time?

Comment: Can I ask  why you are referring specifically to  people living in Calabria?

Comment: @Josh. Dubito, alla luce di un'interpretazione ermeneutica della domanda, che Shirley si riferisca alla gente di tutto il mondo, o anche solo italiana, che passa di lì e che saluta quando è lì.

Comment: If this is a question about Calabrese dialect, it is [mostly considered off-topic](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/31/are-questions-about-dialects-on-topic). Otherwise people in Calabria, just like in Latium or in Piedmont, would probably say *ciao* or *addio* or something like this.

Comment: @DaG addio is for a definitive parting. When they will be reunited after a long time, you woulnd't use that

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia: a situation when two people «will not be reunited for a long time», as the OP says, is quite close to a definitive parting. I'd say *Addio* to somebody who, say, leaves for another continent, but you are free not to.

Answer (score 1):

My parents are from Calabria and, although I've never heard anything like that, I would probably say: *Ndi vidimu prestu*, or *Stai attentu, ndi sintimu* (Take care, we'll keep in touch).

Other ways to say goodbye would be more similar to the italian *Mi mancherai* (I'll miss you).